# Which Raspberry Pis are compatible out of the box?

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, compatibility

First, I googled for this question but found no valid answers (may have been inefficient at this though).

I am working with a mix of Raspberry Pis: Raspberry Pi 1B, 2 B+, 3, Zero. I know that those have different chipsets / architectures etc, but it seems that plugging an SD card created for one Rasberry on a Raspberry of a different model works (I created my SD cards for the 2B+, and plugged them also into other models). I use Raspbian, and I run some code that relies on quite a lot of Python packages (numpy, scipy, etc).

My question is:

- Why would this work at all despite different hardware? Where is the hardware taken into account when doing a `sudo apt-get install`? Are there some parts of a `sudo apt-get` that depend on the RPi model?
- As it seems to be working fine, am I at a risk if I switch cards between different RPi models that the program executes, but that its output is somehow 'wrong'?

Comment: This question is better asked over at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.  It might be appropriate on [raspberrypi.se] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Some* debian/unix packages need to be compiled against specific CPU architectures. Python source code, for the most part, is transferrable because you are not compiling it onto a specific architecture like you would for C/C++

Regarding the SD cards, I wouldn't trust moving them to different models. There are different Linux kernel requirements at least between Pi-1 and the later models.

Although, I see there is only one link to download Rasbian image, the other OS's specifically say "image for Raspberry Pi 2 and 3"

Comment: Ok, thank you. Any idea of what happens when under the hood a python package uses compiled C / C++ / Fortran as does numpy?

Comment: The Pis are all ARM based, but I'm not sure it matters if it's ARMv6 or ARMv7